# Value to index in Q_ENUM

Tags: c++, qt, enums, qt5

`QMetaEnum` contains method to convert enum index to actual value:

```
int value(int index) const
```

But how to convert back to index, for example, if I want to use enum in some control where I need sequence by index?

```
int index(int value) const
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following function:

```
int indexFromValue(const QMetaEnum & e, int value){
    for(int ix=0; ix< e.keyCount(); ix++){
        if(e.key(ix) == e.valueToKey(value))
            return ix;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMetaEnum>
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    enum class FooEnumType { TypeA=10, TypeB=21 };
    Q_ENUM(FooEnumType)
};

static int indexFromValue(const QMetaEnum & e, int value){
    for(int ix=0; ix< e.keyCount(); ix++){
        if(e.key(ix) == e.valueToKey(value))
            return ix;
    }
    return -1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    const QMetaObject &mo = Foo::staticMetaObject;
    int index = mo.indexOfEnumerator("FooEnumType");
    QMetaEnum metaEnum = mo.enumerator(index);
    Q_ASSERT(indexFromValue(metaEnum, 10) == 0);
    Q_ASSERT(indexFromValue(metaEnum, 21) == 1);
    Q_ASSERT(indexFromValue(metaEnum, 100) == -1);
    return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thought about, not beautiful so... Could be used of course if nothing better found.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich 
In simplicity is beauty, :D, it is a simple task.